# rails 3 and phone apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hoping someone can help me out. If I'm developing a Rails 3 app, but later would like have a mobile version later down the line, whether is iphone/bberry or anything else. Does this mean that the mobile apps will be developed from scratch or will they utilize the existing infrastructure somehow?

Does anyone have experience with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what type of mobile app you're talking about. You can create either:

1. A phone friendly version of your web app
2. A native app on the platform of your choice (iphone, bberry, etc)

If you go with #1 all you need to do is create phone friendly versions of your views. But your users will need to use the web browser on their phone to view your site. An example of this is www.engadget.com versus [m.engadget.com](http://m.engadget.com). The latter is just the engadget website optimized for viewing on your phone.

If you go with #2, at the very least you'll need to create a native client app on the platform you select. However, if you design things right you can leverage much of the functionality that's already in your website.

Take twitter as an example. You can use the twitter website to use features of twitter or you can use a native iphone app like twitterific. The iphone app (probably) uses some twitter API to access functionality that's the same as when you use their website.

Comment: If #2, I recommend rhodes which is made in Ruby and really close from Rails

Comment: I agree. Besides Rhodes, PhoneGap will also be a good option. For blackberry, you can also write your application in HTML5 and Javascript to create a native application using their [Webworks SDK](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/browserdev/). All of these frameworks will be an easier transition to writing a native app than writing in the standard language (ObjC or Java)

Answer (score 1):

You will just need new views for mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to probably output the data in the form of json or xmls if it is a native app so you will need to modify your active controllers. If it is web app or web page then you will need to modify your views to make them mobile browser friendly.